# net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED in Angular 2 Firebase App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, http, ssl

I hosted my Node app and MongoDB on a DigitalOcean droplet and Angular App in Firebase. I am able to connect to Node backend from Postman and from my Angular App running locally on port 4200. But when I use my Angular App hosted in Firebase to connect to the Backend in DO Droplet, I get this error in Chrome console.

[image: Error Message in console]

I have added the link of Firebase app in CORS Whitelist Array in Node app, also added backend url in environment.prod.ts file as

```
backednUrl: 'https://***.**.**.***:3000'
```

The Error log doesn't say much in Specific. How do I fix this error? Is this because of any SSL or HTTPS issue?

Comment: may be your server not running port number, check the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of error occurs when the remote server is not listening for requests.

For instance, if no connection is possible (the remote server is not listening for requests on a port, for example), you will get this error:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

In your case you got:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

This error usually has to do with SSL, and your SSL certificate specifically. You need to make sure you have a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: So, I should get a SSL Certificate for my Frontend App Domain or for the Backend Node App?

Comment: The certificate of the server that is using SSL has a problem. What does your browser SSL certificate say? Is it green, or is it yellow/red? Click it and check the text.

Comment: Says "Your connection to this site is not secure.", with an exclamation mark. I have not added any domain to that server, I am using plain IP address to connect to the server.

Comment: That is why you are getting the error. Insecure connection, and so the browser closes it for security reasons. It sounds like you are using https without a valid SSL certificate. How did you enable https? Where did you get your certificate from? Did you do all of that yourself or did the cloud provider set it up for you? If the latter, I would recommend contacting their customer service as they'd be able to best help you.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try purchasing a new domain, set up SSL and then connect to the backed, I hope it should fix the error. I haven't bought SSL certificate yet.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that will most likely be your problem. In order to use https, you need a valid SSL certificate. If the certificate is invalid, the browser will block requests as it did for you, because it assumes there is a security vulnerability there cause people can pretend to be a secure site even when they're not.

Comment: That taught me alot! Installed Nginx, configured it with a SSL from Certbot, then configured my node app in the nginx server and now everything's running smoothly. Thanks a lot for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: You are very welcome :) Feel free to accept the answer if you felt it answered your question.

Comment: Oops, forgot to do that. Done now.

Comment: Also one more question. I updated my front-end angular and backed node with latest repo. When I call newer APIs I added in the backend from my frontend, it says "POST https://*****.***/******404 (Not Found)". Any idea whats this issue?

Comment: This may have to do with the fact that your backend server (the one that you added new endpoints to) needs to be re-started. For instance, if your REST API is an executable in a compiled language like Go, and you add a new endpoint, you must rebuild the executable and start it again for that new endpoint to be active. The "Not Found" error you are getting is basically saying that the endpoint doesn't exist in your API.

Comment: Got it fixed. Just did a server restart and everything works fine. I should have tried that before asking that stupid question! :D Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are no stupid questions :D that same issue happens to me and I guarantee it will continue to happen to you in the future, it's something easy to forget. But the good thing is now that you know how to solve it it will be easy to fix haha.